# Enabling longPathAware in app.manifest works in VS 2019 IDE but fails when app is installed via ClickOnce

Tags: c#, clickonce

My app needed to use long path names in Windows. So I enabled long path names in Group Policy for my PC and added an app.manifest to my application with the following included:

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
     <windowsSettings>
       <longPathAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true</longPathAware>
     </windowsSettings> 
</application>
```

Now my application supports long path names while running in Visual Studio 2019 IDE. But then I publish to a network folder via ClickOnce, and install the application on the exact same PC, and the installed version of the app doesn't support long path names, it throws the "System.IO.PathTooLongException" exception. This is the exact same app that ran fine with long path names in the IDE.

I have tried publishing with "Platform Target" set to Any CPU, X86 and X64 application, same results.

Also, I opened the manifest file being published with the ClickOnce app files and it does include the following:

```
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <longPathAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true</longPathAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
```

Does anyone have any clues as to why long path names are not supported after I install the app and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: ClickOnce deployed apps are started by applaunch.exe.  Which has its own manifest, the one the OS actually uses, and it doesn't contain longPathAware.  Don't use CO if this limitation is critical, the group policy change by itself requires a manual.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the reply. While I have a lot of faith in your knowledge, I also have to think there is some way to make a CO deployed app longPathAware. Do you (or anyone else) know if there is a code based alternative to making an app longPathAware?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved with:
In application StartUp:

```
       Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
        If My.Application.IsNetworkDeployed Then
            Dim U As Uri = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateLocation
            Shell(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\" & My.Application.Info.AssemblyName & ".exe " & U.AbsolutePath.ToUpper, AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, False, 1)
            End
        End If
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be in VB code. The question is about a problem in C#

Comment: private void MyApplication_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    if (My.Application.IsNetworkDeployed)
    {
        Uri U = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateLocation;
        string V = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString;
        Shell(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + @"\" + My.Application.Info.AssemblyName + ".exe " + U.AbsolutePath.ToUpper() + " " + V, AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, false, 1);
        System.Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}